# POS/Inventory for a Variety Store

Tags: odoo, inventory

I'm trying to implement ODOO for a variety store (like 99 Cents, Dollar, etc).
Now, I found out many items do not have UPC.
What's the best way to give input for the items?
What would it work to sell these items on the pos (not upc, not barcode)?
We're talking about thousand of differents items?
Have somebody a document or videos support me? Tutorial or guide

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can assign them local use barcodes. UPC has range for that.